# Virtual machine access globals by index or hash

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, vm-implementation

I am creating my own class based language and virtual machine.
It is statically scoped and I am trying to evaluate pros and cons about using an array versus an hash table to represents slots in a global table.
I know that using an array would be much faster than using an hash table by I am wondering in terms of flexibility what could be the advantages of the hash table implementation.

For example, the code `var a = 1;`
can be represented at runtime as:
    `PUSH 1;`
    `SET_GLOBAL 0;`
where 0 in the `SET_GLOBAL` instruction can represent an index inside a global array or an index inside a constant pool for the identifier "a" (an hash table would be used in this case). My question was about pros/cons of the array/hash usage in this particular case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all let's see what are the requirements of the symbol/global table.

**Symbol/Global Table Requirements :-**               // taken from [this link](http://jcsites.juniata.edu/faculty/rhodes/lt/sytbmgmt.htm)

1. fast lookup.
2. flexible in structure.
3. efficient use of space.
4. handle characteristics of language (e.g., scoping, implicit declaration)

You're incorrect in assuming *I know that using an array would be much faster than using an hash table*. Arrays are OK for languages which are very small and don't need dynamic behaviour implementation.

Nowadays,almost all of the high-level language compilers implement their symbol table using HashTable.

The main points where Array will lag behind HashTable are

1. no flexibility to add new identifiers
2. upto some extent slower lookup than in hashing
3. in case of global variables, chaining will take proper care by referencing to the older entry.

Comment: I am much more interested in what happens at runtime, when byte code has been already produced. I know that at compile time an hash table is the best way to proceed...

Comment: When byte code has already been produced, then much of the work is left for code-optimisation and final target-code generation. There's not much wrk left here for the symbol table!

Comment: @user2004309- I'd suggest you to revise through `the dragon book(Compilers)`. At the later stage, symbol tables are used only for referencing/lookup...

Comment: Unfortunately it is not the answer I was looking for (and I already read the dragon book). For example, the following code: `var a = 1;` can be represented at **runtime** as `PUSH 1;` `SET_GLOBAL 0;` where 0 in the `SET_GLOBAL` instruction can represent an index inside a global array or the position inside a constant pool for the identifier "a" (an hash table would be used in this case). My question was about pros/cons of the array/hash in this particular case...

Comment: @user2004309- You've already adopted the `array(Stack)` approach. Also, so your instruction size has reduced to 2 word. Say,if your strategy would have been to store in HashTable, then your intermediate code/target code will be `triples` OR `quadruples` depending on the way you represent. What you've done seems native and easy coding for a small language. As I've already suggested, then array will be good to work with your naive language...